# Enumerate package wont allow to change format

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, ieeetran, roman-numerals

I have a *[journal]{IEEEtran}* document (I just don't want to change the document type). The command `enumerate` won't let me put, for example, roman numbers. I am doing it this way:

```
\begin{enumerate}[i]
...
\end{enumerate}
```

How do I enumerate with roman numbers then (not loading any other packages)?

Comment: Since this is homework, we should probably not simply post solutions. However, if you're stuck some hints might be helpful. It would be best (whether this is homework or not) if you could post the code you are trying (a Minimum Working Example). Then people can see where you are and help you get unstuck. Depending on what is required, you could think about renewing the `enumerate` environment and adding an optional parameter to handle this. Or you could define a new list environment and use that for roman numbered lists.

Comment: @cfr I am really sorry, you have pointed out something that is really important for education, that is the need of the student to do what he has to. It is a homework but it isn't related to LaTeX.

The reason I've typed that I was not allowed to change the document type is because I really want to know how it works(the IEEE journal), but discovering it by myself, besides: I don't want to bother asking for explanations (and I don't have too much time to read the documentation).

Comment: Oh, if your homework isn't about the formatting, my objections to people giving you code are irrelevant. The way you put it, I had understood these to be constraints set as part of the assignment e.g. "Figure out how to do this and this without changing the class or..." etc. but if the homework is about something else and you're just asking for help formatting that something else, there's no problem at all. ;) Good luck with it - you have several good solutions here!

Comment: Yeah, thank you anyway, (someone actually deleted a really good answer). We are getting too chatty but thanks for your worries.

Comment: My answer has now be un-deleted since the situation has been clarified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use `enumitem`?

**Global modification**:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\roman*}  %% for all enumerate environments
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item One
 \item Two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Local modification:**

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[enumerate]{label=\roman*}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*]
 \item One
 \item Two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Or emulating `enumerate` package:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\setlist[enumerate]{label=\roman*}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[i]
 \item One
 \item Two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you pass `shortlabels` option to `enumitem`, it can emulate the functionality of `enumerate` package. Hence `\begin{enumerate}[i]` is applicable to only one enumerate environment where it is being used.

You can also define a new environment `renumerate` (say)

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{renumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[renumerate]{label=\roman*}
\begin{document}
With \verb|renumerate|:
\begin{renumerate}
 \item One
 \item Two
\end{renumerate}

Regulae \verb|enumerate|:
\begin{enumerate}
 \item One
 \item Two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! I would thank the most if I don't have to load the package `enumitem`

Comment: @Hans `enumitem` can be a life saver. ;-). But you can define a list of your own from scratch. Why do you want to do the hard work unless it is un-avoidable?

Comment: I know but I have loaded like a million packages, and I don't like it, that's all (and the reason of why I typed "_not loading any other packages_").

Comment: @HarishKumar Apparently the homework is not actually about TeX - see discussion in comments on the original question. So I just misunderstood because the way the question was asked made it sound that way. (People do take courses on LaTeX, though, so there certainly could be homework on it.)

Comment: @cfr Thanks. That is what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 4):

Without using any packages, you can simply define a new environment `renum`, for example, which is an `enumerate` with a redefinition of `\labelenumi` to get lower case Roman numerals; the alternating headings can be obtained simply using the `twoside` class option:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran} 

\newenvironment{renum}
  {\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand\labelenumi{\roman{enumi}}}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{renum}
 \item One
 \item Two
\end{renum}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item One
 \item Two
\end{enumerate}

\clearpage% just for the example

test text

\end{document}
```

[image]